# What does double square brackets [[]] mean in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I ran into this RegExp `/[[0]]/` in JavaScript, and have been wondering what it means.

I know that the outer pair of `[]` should be use as a character class, but what about the inner pair? I searched in Google and found [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#coll), but "Collating Sequences" doesn't seem to be it 'cuz I can't get `/[[.some.]]/` work as this page claims.

Thanks in advance if anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: The website says: `I do not know of any regular expression engine that support collating sequences, other than POSIX-compliant engines part of a POSIX-compliant system.`

Maybe thats why it isn't working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
/[[0]]/
```

is equivalent to:

- A `[` or `0` character, followed by a `]` character.

  - Valid matches are:

    - `[]`
    - `0]`
  - Invalid matches:

    - `[0`
  - Valid string, but probably not an expected match:

    - `[0]` (matches `0]`)

In other words: `/(\[|0)\]/` or `/[\[0]\]/`
In real words: `( [ or 0 ) plus  ]`.

Comment: Wow, truely, but why `/(\[|0)\]/` and not `/(\[|0|\])/`? I mean, what makes the `]` following `0` so special?

Comment: @Rufus It's special, because it has already been opened by the `[`.

Comment: @Rufus: Yes. It's still better to escape the characters though, makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Rufus Yes. Unless the `]` is prefixed by an odd number of backslashes.

Comment: @FelixKling & Rob W ,  Thank you both, this is really tricky :)

Comment: i never would have thought this would match what it matches by just looking at it. you should definitely add some explicit escape characters.